# How to get the index of click on function?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array, and inside them is a Boolean field.
Clicking on each item would like to change this value to 'true', it is currently changing, but all items in the list
are being turned to true! How can I change the value of each item only when it is clicked? Still new with React, any help thanks so much!

```
export default class Create extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props); 
this.state = {
  ocorrenciasList: [
    {
      id: 1,
      mes: 'Janeiro',
      numero: '000001',
      isOpened: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      mes: 'Fevereiro',
      numero: '98212',
      isOpened: false,
    }
  ],
 };
 this.openOptions = this.openOptions.bind(this);
 }
 openOptions() {
 this.setState({isOpened: true});
 }
 render() {
 const { isOpened } = this.state;
 const Inicio = () => {  
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.ocorrenciasList.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="cartaozinho">
          <li>{item.mes}</li>
          <li>{item.numero}</li>
          <button className="botao" onClick={() => this.openOptions()}>
            Opções
          </button>          
          {isOpened == true && 'TRUE HERE'}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
return (
  <div>
    <Inicio />
  </div>
)
```

}
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onClick` pass the id:

```
  {this.state.ocorrenciasList.map((item, index) => (
    <div className="cartaozinho">
      <li>{item.mes}</li>
      <li>{item.numero}</li>
      <button className="botao" onClick={() => this.openOptions(item.id)}>
        Opções
      </button>          
      {isOpened == true && 'TRUE HERE'}
    </div>
  ))}
```

And update the state only to that `id`

```
openOptions(id){
    this.setState(prevState =>({
    ocorrenciasList: prevState.ocorrenciasList.map(x =>{
        if(x.id === id) return {...x, isOpened: true}

        return x
    })
}))
}
```